# EF Core - "A command is already in progress"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp-net-core

Estou fazendo a requisição de uma function no banco de dados onde ela me retorna os valores para serem salvos, porém antes de salvar eu preciso fazer uma verificação se não existe dados iguais, quando eu faço essa verificação com o EF core ele me retorna esse erro "A command is already in progress:"

segue código:

```cs
       public void funcCompMargemDesvioPadrao()
        {   


            using (var connection = _context.Database.GetDbConnection())
            {

                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.CommandText = "select * from computer_vision.funccompmargemdesviopadrao()";

                    using (var data = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (data.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (data.Read())
                            {
                                var objDTO = new Compiled_daily_pass_registerDTO();

                                objDTO.entity_id = Convert.ToInt32(data["id"]);
                                objDTO.pass_date_time = Convert.ToDateTime(data["date_time"]);
                                objDTO.qty_daily_pass = Convert.ToDouble(data["qty_comp"]);
                                objDTO.excluded = false;
                                objDTO.updated_at = DateTime.Now;

                                // AQUI QUE RETORNAR O ERRO
                                compiled_daily_pass_register compiled_day = _context.compiled_daily_pass_register.SingleOrDefault(
                                x => x.pass_date_time == objDTO.pass_date_time && x.entity_id == objDTO.entity_id);

                                objDTO.created_at = compiled_day.created_at;

                                compiled_daily_pass_register obj = new compiled_daily_pass_register();
                                obj = _mapper.Map<Compiled_daily_pass_registerDTO, compiled_daily_pass_register>(objDTO, obj);

                                if (compiled_day != null)
                                {
                                    _context.compiled_daily_pass_register.Remove(compiled_day);
                                    _context.compiled_daily_pass_register.Add(obj);
                                    _context.SaveChanges();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();

            }
```

Comment: `_context.SaveChanges();` tem um comando desses no meio de um `DataReader` vai dar errado mesmo ... é por causa disso. Primeiro você cria toda a lista e depois você executa o comando referente ao EF. Na minha visão parece que você também está indo pelo caminho errado, como não tenho como saber e afirmar 100% ...

Comment: Olá @VirgilioNovic, obrigado por me responder, então eu preciso abrir outra conexão com o banco? ou salvar os registros em uma lista e após isso, usar eles para a consulta?

Comment: Você tem que gerar a lista primeiro e depois fazer a operação (eu não sei até que ponto isso é bom, eu não consigo ver o seu problema na real) porque a partir do momento que você pega a conexão de maneira comum e dentro de um `DataReader` se não pode dar um `SaveChanges()` o próprio EF não deixa. Então crie a lista e saia desse `using` ai se faz a operação normalmente. Mas ainda eu acho que é um código ruim, poderia fazer isso talvez de forma melhor é que não consigo realmente ver o que deseja fazer, é muito código

Comment: @VirgilioNovic certo, eu fiz algo muito próximo do que você falou, eu adicionei em uma lista de obj os dados que busco no dataReader, ai quando termina esse loop, fora dele eu faço o outro select para verificar se existe dados iguais, senão existe ele cria um novo e se existe ele faz um update